# SQL - Concat multiple rows into 1 on a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

So I've got 2 tables which looks like the below:

MetaData

```
Id       | Value
---------------------
1       | 5
1       | 6
2       | 6
```

LookUp

```
Value    | Text
---------------------
5       | Car
6       | Truck
```

I need a query to pull out the Id from MetaData and the text from Lookup
so e.g.

```
Id | Text
---------
1  | Car, Truck
2  | Truck
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2017, you would use `string_agg()`:

```
select id, string_agg(l.test, ', ')
from metadata m join
     lookup l
     on m.value = l.value
group by m.id;
```

In earlier versions it is more complicated.  You can Google "SQL Server string aggregation" and get lots of examples on what to do.

Comment: There is a typo - string_agg() works starting with 2017.